# decimal.InvalidOperation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, invalidoperationexception

I was testing my code and I thought that this piece of code was correct:

```
while True:
    try:
        p = Decimal(raw_input(...))
        if ...condition... : break
        else: raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print "Error! ..."
```

but it's not, since when I input "a", this is what I get:

```
File "multiple.py", line 28, in <module>
  precision = Decimal(raw_input(...))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
  "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3872, in _raise_error
  raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: 'a'
```

ValueError does not catch InvalidOperation.
I don't want the program to stop because of that, I want it to keep asking for input until it satisfies the condition. How do I do it?

Comment: You _could_ try catching the `decimal.InvalidOperation` exception...

Comment: @PM2Ring how? `except decimal.InvalidOperation`?

Comment: @Pigna: yes, did you try that yet?

Comment: ok, yes it worked, thanks! I didn't know you could also import errors

Comment: @Pigna: exceptions are just classes, based of `BaseException`. You can always define more subclasses in that hierarchy for specific purposes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The signal exceptions in the `decimal` module are all subclasses of the [`decimal.DecimalException` exception class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.DecimalException). You can catch any of the following exceptions to deal with the `InvalidOperation` exception, from the specific to the (very) generic:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation
decimal.DecimalException
ArithmeticError
Exception
BaseException
```

`ValueError` is not in that hierarchy, but catching `Exception` would also catch `ValueError` since it is a subclass. Generally speaking, you rarely want to catch `BaseException` since that catches *all* possible exceptions, including `SystemExit` and `MemoryError`.

You can catch multiple exceptions in the same handler:

```
from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException

while True:
    try:
        p = Decimal(raw_input(...))
        if ...condition... : break
        else: raise ValueError
    except (ValueError, DecimalException):
        print "Error! ..."
```

would catch both your original `ValueError` exceptions, and all signal exceptions raised by the `decimal` module.